# So I have a folder which contains around 300 png files and I want to convert all of them to jpg files

Tags: converters

i have a access to a Ubuntu server and a macOS installation

I’ve searched only but haven’t found anything

Comment: <sudo apt install imagemagick> then   <mogrify -format jpg *.png>

Answer (score 0):

###### install imagemagick and rename

`sudo apt install imagemagick rename`

###### go in the folder to be safe

`cd /dir/with/pngs`

###### convert them all in a for/do/done loop

```
for png in $(ls -1 *.png); do
   convert "$png" "${png/png/jpg}"
done
```

You win one million fire emojiis.